# Linear Programming: Objective function goodness if variable holds value above a given constant value

Tags: linear-programming

In a Linear Programming formulation, stating that a punishment is to be introduced in a minimized objective function if a variable `S` holds a value above a given constant `K` (`K = 35` in the below example), is quite easy:

1. Variable `M` is included in (minimize) objective function
2. `M >= 0`
3. `S-M-35 <= 0`

Example explanation: If `S` gets value 30, then `M` may be kept at 0, so no punishment in objective function.  However, if `S` gets value 40 in problem solution, `M` is forced to at least 5, and consequently a punishment of 5 is included, just as desired.

But what if we want to include *goodness* in objective function if `S` gets value above 35?  E.g. in the previous example, a value of `S` equal to 30 should (still) not influence the objective function.  But a value of S equal to 40 should *decrease* the objective function cost with 5.

I originally thought this "swap" from badness to goodness would be easy, but I worked on it for almost a full day without finding a solution...

Comment: This is a (very) typical Linear Programming question.

I.e. a Linear Programming formulation question.


I believe I posted inside the Linear Programming section?

Comment: X-posted: https://or.stackexchange.com/q/2911/8 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3407798/339790

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
min f - 3.14 * s2
X = 35 - s1 + s2
```

where

```
s1,s2 >= 0
s1*s2 = 0
```

The complementarity condition can be linearized using binary variables or SOS1 variables or a penalty term in the objective (see below). E.g. using binary variables:

```
s1 <= b*M
s2 <= (1-b)*M
```

where M is a large enough constant. You may get away with

```
min f + 10*(s1+s2) - 3.14*s2
```

but any terms in the objective change the problem. This is not a reliable approach. Background: the problem is non-convex so a pure LP approach should not work.